# Angular typescript on blur input filed to added background CSS not work

Tags: css, angular, typescript

Angular Type script, When I enter the value on the input filed and after I added CSS at the on blur to input filed background change but its not working correctly, dose any one know how to do that correctly?

**html**

```
 <input nz-input placeholder="Type here"  ng-class={red:blur} (blur)="UpdateInvoice(data,$event)" value="{{data.invoiceNum}}" style=width:200px />
```

**css**

```
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: When do you want it to change exactly? Always when the blur event fires? Or rather a more common scenario: when the input is invalid?  And when exactly should it not be red anymore?

Comment: @hogan Hi, When I type after the input field, the user can highlight it and add a background color to it. When I type after, the field  data will be automatically submitted and display on the filed

Comment: Hi sorry, I dont understand.

Comment: @hogan simply i want know how to do ,someone type on the input filed and after type the word then changed the input filed background color

Comment: You wrote "then always input filed to appear in the red color", when should it not be there, just initially or when the user removes the value in the input? There are many ways to solve, you should provide detailed information so that other people know your scenario better.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `blur` is a variable that is set in the `UpdateInvoice` function.
If that is true, you should use

```
[ngClass]="{'red': blur }"
```

to toggle this class. More information on how to use ngClass can be found here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I used that, then always input filed to appear in the red color

Comment: Well, that's probably because your variable named "blur" is always true.